# PromQL difference between memory usage and working set

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, promql

I am trying to determine the Average memory usage of container over a time span

Below is the query I have used in OpenShift 4.9

```
sum by (namespace, pod) (avg_over_time(pod:container_memory_usage_bytes:sum[2d]))
```

The above query does not work in the 4.11 version of OpenShift, so I have tried modifiying the above query like

```
sum by (namespace, pod) (avg_over_time(node_namespace_pod_container:container_memory_working_set_bytes{}[2h])/1048576)
```

Both queries provide different values, though with minor differences.

I am confused on which query to use from the above 2 to determine average memory used by a POD.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between **memory usage** and **working set** in PromQL is that the memory usage means the total amount of memory allocated to a process, while working set is the amount of memory that is **actively** being used by the process. Memory usage includes **both active and inactive memory**, while the working set only includes the memory that is being **actively used**. In other words, the working set is a subset of the memory usage.

The following expression can be used to sum the average pod container memory usage by namespace and pod over a two day period:

```
sum by (namespace, pod) (avg_over_time(pod:container_memory_usage_bytes:sum[2d]))
```

**Recommendation** is to use the following query because memory_working_set will give the memory usage which is actively used.

```
 sum by (namespace, pod) (avg_over_time(node_namespace_pod_container:container_memory_working_set_bytes{}[2h])/1048576)
```

Comment: Did you got any time to check my answer? Is it helpful?